# Is JQUERY inputmask can add string for datetime?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-inputmask, input-mask

Code for masking the time (HH:mm:ss)

```
$('.time').each(function () { 
        $(this).inputmask({
                mask: "h:s:s",
                placeholder: "00:00:00",
                alias: "datetime",
                hourFormat: "24"
        }); 
});
```

How to mask a datetime which also accept a string like NONE? Can type a text but only None value is valid **NONE or 01:00:00**

I'm using the jquery inputmask library(https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `alias` and `mask` since you are not declaring a `alias` but simply calling `inputmask()` with `options`.

Here is the solution with commented explanations.

```
$('.time').inputmask({
    mask:'(h:s:s)|(X)', // X will define our new validator , | mean OR 
    definitions: {
        "X": {
            // Needed since you need the word(NONE) comparaison
            validator: function(chrs) {return chrs.toUpperCase().localeCompare('NONE')==0 },
            cardinality: 4, // Mean 1 instance of our new validator(X) has a value of 4 chars
            prevalidator: [
                {validator: function(chrs){return chrs.toUpperCase().localeCompare('N')==0 },cardinality:1},
                {validator: function(chrs){return chrs.toUpperCase().localeCompare('NO')==0 },cardinality:2},
                {validator: function(chrs){return chrs.toUpperCase().localeCompare('NON')==0 },cardinality:3}
            ],
            casing: "upper" // All chars will be casted as UPPER but not during our custom validation
        }
    }
})
```

With death metal in it :)

```
$('.time').inputmask({
    mask:'(h:s:s)|(X)', // X will define our new validator , | mean OR 
    regex: Inputmask().opts.aliases.datetime.regex, //Needed for the imported validator
    placeholder: "00:00:00", //To get 00:00:00 in place __:__:__
    hourFormat: "24", // or 12
    definitions: {
        "h": Inputmask().opts.aliases.datetime.definitions.h, // first char > 2 will become 09:
        "s": Inputmask().opts.aliases.datetime.definitions.s, //first char for minute/second if > 5 become 09
        "X": {
            // Needed since you need the word(NONE) comparaison
            validator: function(chrs) {return chrs.toUpperCase().localeCompare('NONE')==0 },
            cardinality: 4, // Mean 1 instance of our new validator(X) has a value of 4 chars
            prevalidator: [
                {validator: function(chrs){return chrs.toUpperCase().localeCompare('N')==0 },cardinality:1},
                {validator: function(chrs){return chrs.toUpperCase().localeCompare('NO')==0 },cardinality:2},
                {validator: function(chrs){return chrs.toUpperCase().localeCompare('NON')==0 },cardinality:3}
            ],
            casing: "upper" // All chars will be casted as UPPER but not during our custom validation
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Woah it works! your the man sir greenseed! would it possible to have the same behavior like in datetime when you type it automatically adds 00:00 in 24hrs?

Comment: i am not sure what exactly you asking , you wan `00:00` in place of `__:__` or you wan `08:__` when user type in 8 as first key. Look here [https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/blob/3.x/js/inputmask.date.extensions.js#L224](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/blob/3.x/js/inputmask.date.extensions.js#L224) `maskset` is the current display so just play with it inside prevalidator

Comment: Uhm both? at first its 00:00 instead of _:_ and when user type in 8 first it become 08:00

Comment: look at what happen to `maskset` [here line 224](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask/blob/3.x/js/inputm?ask.date.extensions.js#L224) , this is the code doing `20` when user input `2` as first char for year input , `maskset` is what the user see in the input

Comment: I see.. but dont have that eyes as yours sir.. meaning no idea how to add it to the code. Its a really big help if you can update the answer :)

Comment: you really save my day! it works what I expected! :) kudos sir! rock en roll!